Problem inserting JSON into Postgres using Python
Trying to insert a json file into a JSON column in a Postgres table, the python script shows that the value I'm trying to insert is the JSON file I want, however only a null shows up after the insert is run.  Code Snippet and test JSON file are below
`
import psycopg2
import json
from pathlib import Path
import io

connection = psycopg2.connect(database="DBNAME", user="postgres", password="<password>", host="192.168.55.57", port=5432)

with psycopg2.connect(database="DBNAME", user="postgres", password="<password>", host="192.168.128.57", port=5432) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        file = json.loads(Path("charges_export.json").read_text())
        data = file["data"]
        ordersList = data["ordersList"]
        print (ordersList)
        query_sql = """ insert into ent_core_c.charges (charges)
            select * from json_populate_record(NULL::ent_core_c.charges, %s) """
        cur.execute(query_sql, (json.dumps(data["ordersList"]),))


Sample File:
{
    "data": {
        "ordersList": {
            "edges": [
                {
                    "cursor": "bW9uZ29kYmNvbm5lY3Rpb246MA==",
                    "node": {
                        "createdDate": 1709325679871,
                        "orderNumber": "24-TX-EK-1101",
                        "estimatedClosing": 1710954000000,
                        "purchasePrice": "167,702.00",
                        "status": "CANCELLED",
                        "disbursementDate": 1710954000000,
                        "transactionType": "EK-Single File Purchase",
                        "charges": [
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1310",
                                "payeeName": "SnapDocs",
                                "section": "Additional Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "94.95"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1309",
                                "payeeName": "Robertson Anschutz Vetters, LLC",
                                "section": "Additional Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "100.00"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1308",
                                "payeeName": "Robertson Anschutz Vetters, LLC",
                                "section": "Additional Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "100.00"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1311",
                                "payeeName": "Galveston County District Clerk",
                                "section": "Additional Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "456.00"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1312",
                                "payeeName": "Linebarger Goggan Blair & Simpson",
                                "section": "Additional Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "3,630.92"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1313",
                                "payeeName": "Linebarger Goggan Blair & Simpson",
                                "section": "Additional Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "6,303.11"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1314",
                                "payeeName": "Linebarger Goggan Blair & Simpson",
                                "section": "Additional Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "300.00"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1315",
                                "payeeName": "Linebarger Goggan Blair & Simpson",
                                "section": "Additional Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "150.00"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1206",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Recording Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "245.54"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1202",
                                "payeeName": "Emerald National Title - Recording Account",
                                "section": "Recording Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "86.99"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1201",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Recording Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": "145.54"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1207",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Recording Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "30.00"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": "10.00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1111",
                                "payeeName": "Salem Tax Services",
                                "section": "Title Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "64.95"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1110",
                                "payeeName": "Emerald Title of Texas, LLC",
                                "section": "Title Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "900.00"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1108",
                                "payeeName": "First American Title Guaranty Company",
                                "section": "Title Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1107",
                                "payeeName": "Emerald Title of Texas, LLC",
                                "section": "Title Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1106",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Title Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1105",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Title Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1104",
                                "payeeName": "First American Title Guaranty Company",
                                "section": "Title Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1103",
                                "payeeName": "First American Title Guaranty Company",
                                "section": "Title Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "1,189.00"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1101",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Title Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "0.00"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": "247.60"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1112",
                                "payeeName": "Texas Title Insurance Guaranty Association",
                                "section": "Title Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "2.00"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "1113",
                                "payeeName": "Texas Title Insurance Guaranty Association",
                                "section": "Title Charges",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "401",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Gross Amount Due to Seller",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "167,702.00"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "103",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Gross Amount Due from Borrower",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": "403.14"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "101",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Gross Amount Due from Borrower",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": "167,702.00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "221",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Amount Paid on Behalf of Borrower",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": "565.01"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "219",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Amount Paid on Behalf of Borrower",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": "1,459.60"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "217",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Amount Paid on Behalf of Borrower",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": "8,368.33"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "216",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Amount Paid on Behalf of Borrower",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": "41,925.00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "211",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Amount Paid on Behalf of Borrower",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": "286.80"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "210",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Amount Paid on Behalf of Borrower",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": "303.43"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "202",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Amount Paid on Behalf of Borrower",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": "134,160.00"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "521",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Reductions in Amount Due to Seller",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "565.01"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "519",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Reductions in Amount Due to Seller",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "1,459.60"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "517",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Reductions in Amount Due to Seller",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "8,368.33"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "516",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Reductions in Amount Due to Seller",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "41,925.00"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "511",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Reductions in Amount Due to Seller",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "286.80"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "510",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Reductions in Amount Due to Seller",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "303.43"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lineNumber": "502",
                                "payeeName": null,
                                "section": "Reductions in Amount Due to Seller",
                                "sellerAmount": {
                                    "total": "13,653.46"
                                },
                                "borrowerAmount": {
                                    "total": null
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "accounting": {
                            "disbursements": []
                        },
                        "contacts": {
                            "sourceOfBusiness": [
                                {
                                    "company": null,
                                    "associates": [],
                                    "manualEntry": null,
                                    "type": "TITLE_COMPANY"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "loans": [
                            {
                                "amount": "134,160.00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "properties": [
                            {
                                "address1": "604 19th Avenue North",
                                "state": "TX"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "extensions": {
        "capabilities": [
            "Accounting Data",
            "Order Basic Data"
        ]
    }
}

I've tried moving the Key "up and down" the levels in the file all to now avail, this code snipped works on a much simpler JSON file so my issue may be there.

If the same problem happens with much simpler data ({"hello": "world"} f/e), the space presently used for that data would probably be better spent showing the query demonstrating that nothing was actually inserted.

json_populate_record is relevant when you're trying to convert data from JSON into individual column definitions, but there's no reason for any of that here. Just INSERT INTO ent_core_c.charges(charges) VALUES(%s) should do.

psycopg2 has built in JSON adaptation.

Charles Duffy's comment ended up being the correct approach:

json_populate_record is relevant when you're trying to convert data from JSON into individual column definitions, but there's no reason for any of that here. Just INSERT INTO ent_core_c.charges(charges) VALUES(%s) should do.

